# Looking for a C memcpy equivalent

Tags: rust

#### Most efficient (not secure) way to write bytes from src to dst

I found [copy_nonoverlapping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html)

> pub unsafe fn copy_nonoverlapping(src: *const T, dst: *mut T, count: usize)
> Copies count * size_of::() bytes from src to dst. The source and
> destination must not overlap

The data I am looking to write is located in `buf` at index `4` and I want to write it in `_bytes_buff` at (variable) index `index * MAX_DATA_LENGTH`. `MAX_DATA_LENGTH` is about 64Kb.

However I have some trouble to make it work. See below snippet of my current attempt to write it properly:

```rust
let mut  _bytes_buf:Vec<u8>; // big buffer, we don't know the total size at compilation
let mut buf = [0u8; MAX_DATA_LENGTH]; // small buffer

// [...] we now know the size, I write '3' below to make it simple

let len:usize = MAX_DATA_LENGTH * 3 as usize;
_bytes_buf = Vec::with_capacity(len); // any difference with !vec[0; len] ?
unsafe { _bytes_buf.set_len(len); }

// [...] each time buf has a different content and index is either 0, 1 or 2.

unsafe {
    let dst_ptr = &_bytes_buf[index * MAX_DATA_LENGTH].offset(MAX_DATA_LENGTH as isize); 
    let src_ptr = &buf[4];
    ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(src_ptr, dst_ptr, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
}
```

How could I make it work (the last unsafe block)? I found many information but some are deprecated or outdated so I am looking for the way to do it as of 2021.

Also if it is not optimal way to do it (`copy_nonoverlapping`) I would be very grateful to learn more about how I should do it!

Comment: why not use `copy_from_slice`? as in `_bytes_buf[index*MAX_DATA_LENGTH..(index+1)*MAX_DATA_LENGTH].copy_from_slice(&buf)`

Comment: I need to start at index 4 of `buf`. I could potentially drop the 4 first bytes but it doesn't look like the optimal way to do it? Also I get `move occurs because `_bytes_buf` has type `std::vec::Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait`

Comment: ok so `_bytes_buf[index*MAX_DATA_LENGTH..(index+1)*MAX_DATA_LENGTH-4].copy_from_slice(&buf[4..])` then? and not sure how you get that error since [it works here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1dc780f3f2604bcdbd1ae221833e192).

Comment: also `with_capacity()` + `set_len()` violates the safety requirement that *"The elements at old_len..new_len must be initialized"*.

Comment: I rewrote it as `_bytes_buf = vec![0; MAX_DATA_LENGTH * 3];`

Comment: @kmdreko I was able to make some progress thanks to you and found out that the message occurs if I create the vector in the if statement (which I need to... it should only be created ONCE). see my edit

Comment: If you're asking about a *"borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable"* error, that is an entirely different issue than what you first asked about and needs more context to what you're trying to accomplish. You should post a new question (with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this time) instead of editing as you go.

Comment: I agree, feel free to comment with your answer I will select it, will post a new question with a MCVE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rust's safe version of `memcpy` is [`<[u8]>::copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice):

```
const MAX_DATA_LENGTH: usize = 64000;

let mut bytes_buf = vec![0u8; MAX_DATA_LENGTH * 3];
let buf = [0u8; MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
let index = 0;

bytes_buf[index*MAX_DATA_LENGTH..(index+1)*MAX_DATA_LENGTH-4].copy_from_slice(&buf[4..]);
```

If you *really* want to the more direct equivalent, [`copy_nonoverlapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html), this is how to do it:

```
unsafe {
    let dst_ptr = &mut bytes_buf[index*MAX_DATA_LENGTH] as *mut u8;
    let src_ptr = &buf[4] as *const u8;
    std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(src_ptr, dst_ptr, MAX_DATA_LENGTH-4);
}
```

However, don't use `unsafe` unless necessary and you understand the safety guarantees you need to ensure to make it *safe*.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kmdreko that was very helpful! Any idea if `copy_nonoverlapping` would provide any advantage over `copy_from_slice` ? (memory and runtime wise)

Comment: The only difference is a [size check](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#2758-2784).

Comment: Ok thanks! I will go for the unsafe approach as I already know the size, so I don't need to check it. Funny side-note: With `copy_nonoverlapping` I get `'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 65503'` vs `panicked at 'range end index 131002 out of range` for `copy_from_slice` which also indicates that the unsafe method is faster (no size check). ;)

Comment: I strongly urge against it, this guards you from making changes that end up reading or writing out of bounds. For example, the attempt in your post did not account for the 4-byte header when doing the copy. The `copy_from_slice` method would catch that, but the `copy_nonoverlapping` method would **not**. You're also copying 64kb at a time, an `if` won't make a meaningful difference in performance to necessitate using `unsafe`.

Comment: "I'm gonna use the unsafe one, because I know the size already" is how every single buffer overflow ever happened ... just saying.

Comment: Nice.  Any idea how to do this with 2d arrays?

Comment: @sbeskur depends on what you mean. Both the above methods are generic over the element type so you can easily use it to copy the 1d-arrays from one 2d-array to another. But if you only wanted to copy a subset from the 1d-arrays then you'd need to do something else (a for-loop for instance); the above functions only work for contiguous elements.

Comment: @kmdreko thanks for you reply.  Let me give it at try but to be clear I'm receiving an array of bytes over the network that I know to be a 2d array serialized from C++ and I wish only to "memcpy" this into and equivalent 2d arrat in Rust.

Comment: Just pointing out that I myself upvoted @JoachimSauer comment 2 years ago. It did not apply to the code I wrote as I have a size check (`if`) right above `copy_from_slice `

The full code is available online, original goal was to send a file from one peer to another (kind of like torrents) as fast as possible: https://github.com/agavrel/tokio_udp_peers